# Is it halal to play soccer?

Tags: halal-haram

Is playing soccer halal in Islam? I want to just play soccer without doing betting and without doing harams.

Answer (score 1):

Soccer is halal, as long as it doesn't distract you from your prayers and from remembering allah.